# rcytoscapejs: varying parameters- 'renderGraph' function unavailable

Tags: graph, shiny, shinyjs

I need to allow users to upload a file to define a network being rendered in an app.

I would like to vary the parameters to re-render an interactive shiny graph that is deployed via a special shiny github package- "rcytoscapejs": https://github.com/cytoscape/r-cytoscape.js/tree/master

While the graph deploys fine, my problem is that it can only be deployed from the UI, independently of the server...

```
 g<-createCytoscapeJsNetwork(nodeData = nodes, edgeData = edge)
 #ui.R
 dashboardBody(
  sliderInput(inputId="num", label="Choose coef", value=2, min=1, max=3),
  rcytoscapejs(g$nodes, g$edges)
 )
```

As you can see this is completely impartial from the server, when I try to implement the code within the server via something like this:

```
 #ui.R
 graphOutput("graph")
 #server.R
 output$graph<-renderGraph({rcytoscapejs(g$nodes, g$edges)})
```

I have tried "graphOutput" and "renderGraph" but the functions doesn't seem to exist...

I tried downloading the "renderGraph" from github.

```
 devtools::install_github("mfontcada/renderGraph");
 Downloading GitHub repo mfontcada/renderGraph@master
 from URL https://api.github.com/repos/mfontcada/renderGraph/zipball/master
 Error: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
```

But that package is in version 0.1 and hasn't been updated since 2014...

So ultimately my question is how can I vary the parameters of something that resides in the "ui.R" code???

Something like the following, (file upload code taken from: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html):

```
  server <- function(input, output) {
   dataInput <- eventReactive(input$choices, {
     inFile <- input$file1
     if (is.null(inFile))
       return(NULL)
       read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
     createCytoscapeJsNetwork(nodeData = nodes, edgeData = edge)
   })
  }

#ui.R  
actionButton("choices", "Run analyses"),
fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
          accept = c(
            'text/csv',
            'text/comma-separated-values',
            'text/tab-separated-values',
            'text/plain',
            '.csv',
            '.tsv'
          ),
 rcytoscapejs(dataInput()$nodes, dataInput()$edges),
```

This of course returns an error as one can not vary parameters within the ui.R script as such ....

Any tips on how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1):

sorted it out with the functions renderRcytoscapejs for the server and rcytoscapejsOutput for the UI also must conserve the class of the data file being read into a reactive value with read.csv with isolate():

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(rcytoscapejs)
p1<-cor(t(E.rna_small[1:20,1:20]),use="p") #correlations taken from sample of matrix
library(graph) #as per P Shannon's help must convert to way that is compatible with RCyjs
library(RCyjs)
library(igraph)
g<-igraph.to.graphNEL(simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(p1, weighted=T)))
edge<-as.data.frame(get.edgelist(simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(p1, weighted=T))))
colnames(edge)<-c("source", "target")
nodes<-cbind(id=colnames(p1), name=rownames(p1))
class(nodes)
nodes<-as.data.frame(nodes)
b<-createCytoscapeJsNetwork(nodeData = nodes, edgeData = edge)
uiactual <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="zoom"),
  dashboardSidebar(menuItem(
                   checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                   radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                c(Comma=',',
                                  Semicolon=';',
                                  Tab='\t')
                                )),

                   menuItem(p('If you want a sample .csv or .tsv file to upload,',
                     'you can first download the sample',
                     a(href = 'mtcars.csv', 'mtcars.csv'), 'or',
                     a(href = 'pressure.tsv', 'pressure.tsv'),
                     'files, and then try uploading them.'
                   ))),
  dashboardBody(
    sliderInput(inputId="num", label="Choose coef", value=2, min=1, max=3),
    rcytoscapejsOutput("g3plot"),
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
              accept = c(
                'text/csv',
                'text/comma-separated-values',
                'text/tab-separated-values',
                'text/plain',
                '.csv',
                '.tsv'
              )
    )
  )
)

  serveractual <- function(input, output) {
    g3 <- reactive({
      inFile <- input$file1
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

      isolate(t<-read.table(inFile$datapath, header = T,
                            sep = "\t"))
      #t<-for(i in colnames(t)){
      # as.numeric(t[,i])
      #}

      p1<-cor(t(t),use="p") #correlations taken from sample of matrix
      simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(p1, weighted=T))
      edge<-as.data.frame(get.edgelist(simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(p1, weighted=T))))
      colnames(edge)<-c("source", "target")
      nodes<-cbind(id=colnames(p1), name=rownames(p1))
      nodes<-as.data.frame(nodes)
      createCytoscapeJsNetwork(nodeData = nodes, edgeData = edge)
    })


    output$g3plot = renderRcytoscapejs({
      rcytoscapejs(g3()$nodes, g3()$edges)
    })

  }
shinyApp(uiactual, serveractual)
```